# How can I prove, that $\mu_* (A) \le \mu^*(A)$ for $A \in 2^X$, $\mu_* (A) = \mu^* (A)$ if $A$ is $\mu^*$ measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

We have ($X$, $\mathcal{A}$, $\mu_0$)

Let's define the measure:

$$\mu^{*}(A) = \inf \left\{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu_0 (A_n) \: | \: A_n \in \mathcal{A}, A \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \right\}$$ where $\mu_0 (\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu_0 (A_n)$

We call $A \subset X$ $\mu^{*}$-measurable, if $\forall_{E \subset X}$ the following condition is true: $$\mu^{*}(E) = \mu^{*}(E \cap A) + \mu^{*}(E \cap A^C)$$

$\mu_*$ is defined as follows: $$\mu_* (A) = \mu_0 (X) - \mu^* (X \backslash A)$$

How can I prove, that $\mu_* (A) \le \mu^*(A)$ for $A \subset 2^X$, $\mu_* (A) = \mu^* (A)$ if $A$ is $\mu^*$ measurable? I can't find the proof for this anywhere, I tried to find the prove but it has lead to nothing.

Comment: Just some thoughts: if $A$ is finite, it holds that $\mu^*(X\setminus A) = \mu^*(X) - \mu^*(A)$. Also $\mu^*\leq\mu_0$ by definition of the infimum.

Comment: What is $\mathcal A$? Is $\mu_0$ a measure?

Comment: Is $\mu_0$ defined in terms of itself?

Comment: @amsmath (and also copper.hat) No, it's not. Only the one condition I've given which should hold for $\mu_0$, and also that $\mu_0 (\varnothing) = 0$. It is also stated that $\mu_0$ is a "finite" function on the sets of $\mathcal{A}$

Comment: @anon I'm sure this condition is only supposed to hold for pairwise disjoint $A_n$.

Comment: @amsmath you're right, I've forgot to mention that but it's also stated in the exercise

Comment: Well, we don't see your exercise. And you still haven't said what $\mathcal A$ is.

Comment: @amsmath $\mathcal{A}$ is a sigma-algebra (so that for the pairwise disjoint $A_n$ it is true, that $\bigcup_n^{\infty} A_n \in \mathcal{A}$ if $\left\{A_j\right\}_j\in \mathcal{A}$

Comment: @lmaosome And that's the problem I'm having, I am always getting a contradiction with this approach: $\mu_* (A) = \mu_0 (X) - \mu^* (X \backslash A) \ge \mu^* (X) - \mu^*(X \backslash A) = \mu^* (A)$. So there must be something wrong with this approach. Maybe this should be used to prove that $\mu^* = \mu_*$ if $A$ is $\mu^*$ measurable? So that the condition that $\mu_0 (A) \ge \mu^* (A)$ only holds if $A$ is $\mu^*$ measurable? So because for any arbitrary $A$ we already have $\mu_* \le \mu^*$, this would prove that it should be $=$ if $A$ is $\mu^*$ measurable

Comment: yes! and if $A$ is $\mu^*$-measurable we have that $\mu^*(X) = \mu^*(A) + \mu^*(X\setminus A)$. Thus $\mu_*(A) = \mu_0(A) - \mu^*(X) + \mu^*(A)\leq\mu^*(A)$.